# React Native net-info

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to add an offline notification bar into my app, I have the following code that is called from my App.js.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Dimensions, StyleSheet,Alert } from 'react-native';
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

const dimensions = Dimensions.get('window');
let outofaction = 1;


NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
  console.log("Connection type", state.type);
  console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
  if (state.isConnected == false) {
    outofaction = 0;
  } else {
    outofaction = 1;
  }
});

//class OfflineNotice extends PureComponent {
const OfflineNotice = () => {
  NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
    console.log("Connection type", state.type);
    console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
    if (state.isConnected == false) {
      outofaction = 0;
    } else {
      outofaction = 1;
    }
  });
  
 // Subscribe
const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
  console.log("Connection type", state.type);
  console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);

  if (state.isConnected == false) {
    outofaction = 0;
  } else {
    outofaction = 1;
  }
});

// Unsubscribe
unsubscribe();

function MiniOfflineSign() {
  if (outofaction == 0) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.offlineContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.offlineText}>Offline</Text>
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.offlineContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.offlineText}>Online</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

return (
   <MiniOfflineSign />
)};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  offlineContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#b52424',
    height: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: dimensions.width,
    position: 'absolute',
    top:40,
    zIndex:1
  },
  offlineText: { color: '#fff' }
});

export default OfflineNotice;
```

The code works partially. I start Online, then turn off my internet on my laptop, and if I refresh / reload, then it will show offline.

Two problems I have;

1. I want it to update in near real-time when the isConnected changes (this doesn't appear to be happening)
2. It doesn't get stuck on one state (though item 1 above would fix that)

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar, this might help you with things.

NoInternetMessageBar component

```js
// NoInternetMessageBar.js
import Netinfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { Store } from 'store/Store';

export default function NoInternetMessageBar() {
  const {
    state,
    actions: { networkConnectionChanged },
  } = useContext(Store);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = Netinfo.addEventListener(({ isConnected }) => networkConnectionChanged(isConnected));

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  if (state.isConnected) return null;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.message}>Cannot reach internet</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    height: 40,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
  },
  message: {
    color: 'white',
    marginLeft: 20,
  },
});
```

action

```js
  const networkConnectionChanged = async isConnected => {
    return dispatch({
      type: NETWORK_CHANGED,
      payload: isConnected,
    });
  };
```

reducer

```js
    case NETWORK_CHANGED:
      return {
        ...state,
        isConnected: action.payload,
      };
```

On top level use it like this.

```js
<>
  <AppContainer />
  <NoInternetMessageBar />
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are unsubscribing from NetInfo updates immediately after subscribing to them. Functional components are just that - functions. The code you wrote in there will be executed every time that component renders.

You should instead put your subscribe/unsubscribe in a `useEffect` hook, so that you subscribe on mount and unsubscribe on unmount.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
    ...
  });

  return () => {
    unsubscribe();
  }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe in componentDidMount() and Unsubscribe in componentWillUnmount(), like this -

```js
class A extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.unsubscribe;
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(...);
}

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe && this.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```